# Handlebars.js custom helper to count nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I want to make a custom helper to give `{{count}}` the value of an increasing number based on the number of answers. I'm having trouble getting the right equation and building the helper. I've had several attempts using the values of the parent `{{@index}}` and nested `{{@index}}` to no avail.

The purpose of this is to render a form under each question with radio buttons to select each answer. I need individual IDs to be the same on both the `ID` attribute on the `input` tag and the `for` attribute on the `label` tag. Thx.

NB the other attributes (`name`, `value` etc.) have been programmed correctly so I'm giving thm hard values in this example.

```
{{#questions}}
<div class="question-{{@index}}">
  <form>
    {{#each answers}}
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radios[0]" id="radios-{{count}}" value="1">
      <label for="radios-{{count}}">Answer 1</label>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  <form>
</div>
{{/questions}}

Desired output in plain text class names:

div.question-0
    div
        input#radios-0
        label[for=radios-0]
    div
        input#radios-1
        label[for=radios-1]
div.question-1
    div
        input#radios-2
        label[for=radios-2]
    div
        input#radios-3
        label[for=radios-3]
    div
        input#radios-4
        label[for=radios-4]
div.question-2
    div
        input#radios-5
        label[for=radios-5]
    div
        input#radios-6
        label[for=radios-6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
{{#questions}}
{{questionIndex @index}}
<div class="question-{{@index}}">
  <form>
    {{#each answers}}
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="radios[{{../questionIndex}}]" id="radios-{{../questionIndex}}{{@index}}" value="{{value}}">
      <label for="radios-{{../questionIndex}}{{@index}}">{{answer}}</label>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  <form>
</div>
{{/questions}}

Handlebars.registerHelper('questionIndex', function(value) {
  this.questionIndex = Number(value);
});
```

`{{../questionIndex}}{{@index}}` will result in: 00, 01, 10, 11, 20, 21 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `registerHelper` method to add individual incremental counter

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
    {{#each questions}}
    <div class="question-{{@index}}">
      {{#each answers}}
      <div class="answer-{{count}}"></div>
      {{/each}}
    </article>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var inputdata = {
        questions: [
            { answers: [2,3,4,5] },
            { answers: [1, 2,3,4,5] }
        ]
    };
     var Counter = 1;
    Handlebars.registerHelper('count', function() {
         return Counter ++;
    });

    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());    
    $("body").html(template(inputdata));
</script>
```

## DEMO

Comment: Thanks, this does work, I neglected to state that `{{count}}` may be used more than once per instance of an answer, so this would increase each time the helper is called. I'll update the question.

Comment: `{{count}}` will increment on each time rendering template, you can user more `registerHelper` when you need to place counter more places like {{count1}} with another `registerHelper('count1', ....)` helper